# Not able share file from remote server to Ubuntu NFS share path

Tags: server, mount, nfs

We have configured a vSFTP server on openstack where it is using a NFS mount point to store files from external servers.

External server uses a script, which exports to the NFS path on the Ubuntu server. This fails. The same command is successful when it uses command from external server.

brm backup-manager DEFAULT backup SCHEDULED_BACKUP-2022-09-25T02:00:00.493684+08:00 export uri sftp://pccsftpuser@1xxxxxx:22/home/pccsftpuser/test XXXXXX

```
root@vsftp-vm01:/nfs/5gc_backup/pcc/DEFAULT# df -kh
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       1.6G  696K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/vda1                   3.8G  1.8G  2.0G  48% /
tmpfs                       7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15                  105M  4.4M  100M   5% /boot/efi
10.xxxxx:/Pool1   12T  529G   12T   5% /nfs/gc_backup
10.xxxxx:/Pool2   25T  1.1G   25T   1% /nfs/ss_backup
tmpfs                       1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Appreciate your support troubleshoot this issue

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic